# Do I remove the screw keeper on a self-grounding outlet?

Tags: electrical, grounding, installation

I'm installing Leviton 16252 Backwire Outlets into properly grounded metal boxes. These are self-grounding outlets, so I will, thankfully, be leaving the green screw alone.

At one mounting screw is the wipe to ensure that the ground is picked up from the box.

At the other mounting screw is a plastic/cardstock screw keeper to prevent the screw from falling out.

[image: Back side of Leviton 16252 outlet with screw keeper circled]
<sup>Yes, I've removed the ears because my mud rings aren't quite deep enough and I've learned that these are useful as factory supplied washers.</sup>

I presume it's OK to leave this on to do its job, however, the [Leviton documentation](https://www.leviton.com/en/docs/Instruction+Sheet.pdf) (PDF) is silent on the subject.

If I leave this screw keeper on, will I still get proper outlet grounding?

Comment: It has been a few years since I have played with them, but those ones had a small adjustment slot where the screw went in.  Just wondering if those washers also help keep tension between the device and box to stop movement.  Besides letting you lose the screw and going back to the store for a new one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You report that the keeper is **only** on the screw **without** the contact spring, so it's fairly obvious from here that the screw with the spring is the one that does the important contacting, so on this one it won't matter.

The failure to explicitly mention removing it before installation suggests that it does not need to be removed, or the instructions (which are part of the UL listing) **would** explicitly tell you to remove it.

So, no need to remove it, unless you want to.

Comment: It does seem fairly obvious, but... I wanted to be sure.

Comment: If there's nothing in the instructions saying to remove it, or that removal is optional, then the UL listing is that the outlet is to be installed without removing it. It would only be OK to remove it, and still be in compliance with the UL listed installation instructions, if the instructions said you could remove it. If the instructions don't say, then it should be left in the state it was in from the factory, unless that state is inherently altered by following another instruction (e.g., the keeper will be moved towards the head of the screw when the screw is tightened).

Answer (score 3):

You will get proper grounding because the opposite screw pulls the metal frame of the outlet to the metal ring.  Both screws have their threads contacting the mud ring as well.

Just be sure that even if the outlet is spaced out from the mug ring to be properly aligned for the wall that the mounting screws are snug.